Providing ps1 script an object returned from GET Request
first question here,
Im trying to use Powershell (more of a Mac user) to preform a repetitive task,
and I'd like to register the task to TaskSchedular using another script and the New-ScheduledTask and Register-ScheduledTask cmdlets.
In the Registering (main) script I'm making a GET request to a backend I built and returns json representing a config basically.
Then using the New-ScheduledTask -Action $action Im providing the response object (which is accessible in the main script) to the subscript. When I'm trying to access the object from within the subscript I get null, but I seem to be able to Write-Host "$response" the object...
The task itself is registered successfully but the subscript can't execute.
Example Code
# Registering script
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "http://localhost:3000/api/config/$oid" -Method Get

$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "powershell.exe" -Argument "-NoProfile -File `"$scriptPath`" -Response `"$($response)`""

Write-Host "id is : $id" // prints "id is : <correct expected id>" ✅

$immediateTrigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At (Get-Date).AddSeconds(3)

$task = New-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $immediateTrigger 

# Register the scheduled task
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskName -InputObject $task

#subscript
Param (
    [string]$Response
)

Write-Host "response is : $Response" // prints configuration

$id = $Response.ObjectId

Write-Host "id is : $id" // prints "id is :" 



I tried
ConvertTo-Json and ConvertFrom-Json within the subscript (no Error but didn't work) and from the Registering script to the subscript (Errored with invalid json) but nothing worked.
Also tried capturing the object as PSCustomObject in the subscript, didn't seem to do much.
When im logging property is : $response.property I get property is :    
I've tried using legacy approach as suggested by Microsoft $myObject = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $response but nothing.

Why are you casting $response to a string?  Remove the casting and then try replacing Write-Host with this :  Write-Host "response is : "; $Response"  Make sure you include the semicolon.  $response will display all the properties.

hey thanks for the comment, Ive tried that as well, unfortunately nothing.

Remove the [string] from Param.  It is wrong.  Does $Response return anything?  Where do you call the subscript PARAM?

$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "powershell.exe" -Argument "-NoProfile -File "$scriptPath" -Response "$($response)""
Ive tried enconding the command and then passing it in the action -Argument  using -EncodedCommand $encoded as ChatGPT suggested but that also failed. Interestingly when printing from the subscript $args it results a string representation of the $Response. However Accessing args[0] return just a string of the first word (first key of the object)

You do not have $args in you cmdlet so it must be a global variable that is set by a cmdlet that is called in you PS internally.  It may not be an array and is returning a singleton.  You can force PS to make it an array using @($args)[0]

However this is still not the desired behavior, I think this happens due to how taskscheduler executes the action. If im trying to reproduce by executing the script from a normal ps session it works fine.

The Task Schedular by default runs with a System Account which doesn't have an Environment.  Normally you create a service account which has an environment and has Admin privilege (or use a user account which may or may not have Admin).  Then start service with Run As using an account.
